# No captura excepción al intentar un delete con jdbc

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

Utilizando JDBC , tengo 2 tablas (Alumnos y Módulos) y una tercera que relaciona ambas (Notas), intento borrar a posta un registro de la tabla alumnos que se encuentra en otra tabla (Notas) y no captura el error que se produce cuando quieres borrar un registro que es una referencia de otra tabla...

Alguien me explica porque sucede esto? Debo crear yo mismo la excepción?

```
  tabla Alumnos = id,nombre
  tabla Modulos = id,nombre
  tabla Notas = id_Alumno, id_Modulo



  public static void eliminarAlumno() throws SQLException {

    Statement stmt = null;

    
    String query = "delete from alumnos where id=1;";  --> //este alumno esta en Notas

    try {
        stmt = Gestor_conexion.con.createStatement();
        stmt.executeUpdate(query);
        System.out.println("Alumno borrado");
    } catch (SQLException f) {
        System.out.println("No se pudo borrar el alumno");  -->// NO captura el error
        f.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        stmt.close();
    }

}
    ERROR:
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:117)
    at 
   
  com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdateInternal(StatementImpl.java:1333)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeLargeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:2106)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1243)
```

Comment: ¿Por qué estás declarando `throws SQLException` en este caso? Si vas a manejar la excepción dentro del método mediante el bloque `try ... catch` no necesitas declarar `throws`. Prueba a quitarlo y dinos si la excepción es capturada.

Comment: Corresponde al close() del finally, de todas formas no ha cambiado el error: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`notaslinkia`.`notas`, CONSTRAINT `notas_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_alumno`) REFERENCES `alumnos` (`id`))

Comment: Ok, el problema es que no se está levantando una `SQLException` realmente, sino una `SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException`, si quieres capturar también esa excepción, pon algo como esto: `} catch (SQLException | SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException   f) {` Asumo que usas Java 7+, que te permite capturar varias excepciones separadas por `|` en el mismo bloque, si no es así, deberás poner un `catch` aparte para la nueva excepción.

Comment: Genial, solucionado !